# Degrading performance when using large packets

Tags: ubuntu, dpdk

I have been testing the f-stack and the f-stack performs really well when the packet size is small, like 64 ~ 1024 bytes. However, when the packet size increase up to certain point. I have noticed that it is worse than original TCP polling.

I have been testing both latency and the throughput using client and server pingpong implemented with the f-stack.

I am suspecting that the current NIC's MTU speed has to do with something 
since when I type like this below, I get this:

```
ifconfig| grep MTU 
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1        
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1        
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
```

Here is the result graph of latency:
[image: latency result graph]

As you can see the f-stack performance decreases when the packet size is more than 1500.

Here is the result graph of throughput:
[image: throughput result graph]

Is there a way to increase the f-stack performance with the big packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTU is the maximum transition unit, and it is typically 1500, so in theory TCP packet size is limited to 64K, but Ethernet MTU size limits it. See this for thorough discussion: https://www.lifewire.com/definition-of-mtu-817948.
In a nutshell, yes you are right, and you did perfectly good and valid testing. Good work!
To increase the performance, you have to increase MTU. This is the answer. However, that is not always possible.

Comment: Thanks for the question @Andriy, I answered the question at the bottom of comment.

Comment: @VladP Thanks for the answer. however in that case would it be possible to know exactly why TCP manages the maintain a limited good performance? Is there a inner mechanism that prohibits TCP having  bigger packetsize or something?

Comment: @Sungho, Ethernet packet wraps TCP packet. My guess is that this is the reason, since the maximum Ethernet packet length is smaller than the maximum possible TCP packet length. I do not think that this could be resolved in an easy way, however, I may be missing something.

Comment: Sometimes, you may increase MTU size, but only for certain kind of equipment. See this: http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/nov/5/mtu-manipulation/